# How to prove G is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G = \mathbb R\setminus\{-1\}$. Prove that G is a group with respect to the binary operation $x*y = xy + x + y$, where $xy$ and $x + y$ denote the usual multiplication and addition of reals, respectively.

Comment: Just check the group axioms. I don't think it is something hard.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You just have to verify the group axioms, i.e. that $G$ is closed under $*$; that it contains inverses w.r.t. to $*$; that it contains a unit for $*$ and that $*$ is associative.

Comment: Note that $xy+x+y=(x+1)(y+1)-1$. As such, since the reals are an integral domain, the only way $x*y=-1$ is if $x+1=0$ or $y+1=0$. That shows that the set is closed under the operation. The rest of the properties hold from the corresponding properties of multiplication and addition.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972316/is-mathbbr-where-ab-abab-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1).